# Запись значения select в БД

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
    function addgroup(){
    echo '<h5><center>Додати группу</center></h5>';

        $addcategory = '
    <form method="POST">
    <div class="row"><div class="col s12">
    <p>Примітки <input type="text" name="text">
    <h5><center>Розклад<i class="material-icons">access_time</i></center></h5>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
    <center><h5>Понеділок</h5></center>
    <input type="text" name="t1"><p>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
    <center><h5>Вівторок</h5></center>
    <input type="text" name="t2"><p>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
    <center><h5>Середа</h5></center>
    <input type="text" name="t3"><p>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
    <center><h5>Четверг</h5></center>
    <input type="text" name="t4"><p>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
    <center><h5>П`ятниця</h5></center>
    <input type="text" name="t5"><p>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
    <center><h5>Субота</h5></center>
    <input type="text" name="t6"><p>
    </div>
    '.select_add_group().'
    <p><center><a class="waves-effect red btn"><input type="submit" name="ok"></a></center></div></div>
    </form>';
    echo $addcategory;

    $login=$_SESSION['login'];
    $text=$_REQUEST['text'];
    $t1=$_REQUEST['t1'];
    $t2=$_REQUEST['t2'];
    $t3=$_REQUEST['t3'];
    $t4=$_REQUEST['t4'];
    $t5=$_REQUEST['t5'];
    $t6=$_REQUEST['t6'];
    $ok=$_REQUEST['ok'];
    $select = $_REQUEST['select_category'];

    if ($ok==true){
    $add = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO groups (text, login, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, category, teacher) VALUES ('$text', '$login', '$t1', '$t2', '$t3', '$t4', '$t5', '$t6', '$select', '$teacher')");
    if ($add==true){
    echo "Група додана";
         echo "<HTML><HEAD>
          <META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=admin.php?action=group'>
          </HEAD>";
} else echo "Ошибка";
}
}



function select_add_group(){

    $res=mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM disc");

    echo '<select class="browser-default" name="select_category">';
    for ($x=0; $x<count($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)); $x++  )
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>'; 
    }
    echo '</select></div>';
}
```

Приходит пустое значение в базу. Буду благодарен за любые подсказки.

Comment: А каким образом вызывается `addgroup()`?

Comment: С помощью вызова через action